# Is it possible to compute the mean/median of an variable by a contingency table?

Tags: mean, median, contingency-tables

A contingency table contains the frequencies of two discretized variables. To be more specific, the discretization is done by splitting the spectrum of a signal into equal width intervals. Is it then possible to compute the mean or median interval by such a contingency table?

Comment: I am taking "mean or median interval" just to imply "mean or median".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only approximately at best, and that means that the approximation could be poor.

You can try it yourself.

Here is an example: I have equal frequencies for values 49 and 99 but hide them, but I show you those equal frequencies but for bins 0-50 and 50+-100.

If you guess at midpoints 25 and 75 for your bins, you will guess a mean of 50. But the mean is really 74.

That's an example concocted to make the point, but the principle is simple: information thrown away can't be recovered.

The more bins you have and the more evenly values are distributed within each bin, the less that may bite.

Comment: That last comment is apt: a signal typically is a rich dataset and even when discretized should offer relatively high resolution for estimating descriptive statistics.

Comment: As usual @whuber is absolutely correct. The warning that this **could be** a really bad method can be coupled consistently with the advice that it may be fine. Older pre-computer textbooks were packed with approximate methods of calculation based on groupings of the data and science didn't noticeably suffer: in fact all science is based on approximations almost everywhere. Arguably, we are not free of the downside of that period (e.g. why are histograms still taught so much?).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @NickCox. Usually, i have 50 - 100 bins for a signal. Thus, the approximation should be good enough. Now i can compute the mean by adding up the multiplication of each interval-midpoint with the respective frequency and then divide by the overall frequency count, right?

Comment: Using frequencies as weights is indeed the standard method.

Comment: Are there any other methods?

Comment: There are many other methods of estimating means, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: I know there are quite a few methods for computing means in general, but for me it looks like that this is the only method, in which a mean could be computed for my case.

Comment: Binning can be made consistent with trimming or Winsorizing, for example.

Comment: Unfortunatly, i cannot change the binning. I only have different contigency tables for different signal pairs. Some have like 100 bins for a signal, some just 50. Or did I misunderstood your last comment? (besides: thanks for answering so patiently :-) )

Comment: My previous comment doesn't assume that binning is under anyone's control. All this is moot unless you have grounds for distrusting your estimates.